# Python send a file via ftp with the random file name

Tags: python, file, ftp

Hi i have created a script , to send a file called office-data.txt on a ftp server , but I would like that this script, when the file is sended to a FTP server, must change its name randomly , only remotely  ,for example office-data-12478.txt or office-data-22478.txt and the randomly generated name must never be the same each time the script starts , how can I modify this script to change the file name when it is sent to an FTP server ?

```css
import ftplib

sftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com','userexample','passexample') # Connect
fp = open('office-data.txt','rb') # file to send
sftp.storbinary('STOR office-data.txt', fp) # Send the file

fp.close() # Close file and FTP
sftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) or the current timestamp as milliseconds.

```
import ftplib
import uuid

unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
sftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.exampple','userexample','passexample') # Connect
fp = open('office-data.txt','rb') # file to send
sftp.storbinary('STOR office-data-{0}.txt'.format(unique_id), fp) # Send the file

fp.close() # Close file and FTP
sftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate random names with UUID.

```
import uuid

sftp.storlines(filename + str(uuid.uuid4()), open(filename, 'r'))
```